# Control an Android Tablet with an Android Phone

Tags: android

Is there any way to control my Android Tablet with my Android Phone? Is this possible? I would like to develop an application so I could control my tablet with my phone. Like if I push on a button on my phone that on my tablet an action occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Develop in a Server/Client way.
-One apk for your Tablet as Server, listening for Client to connect.
Once connected, you can exchange data, and then perform actions.
-One apk for your Smartphone as Client, connecting to your Server apk.

Look for Socket, shouldn't be hard to implement.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with a Bluetooth or a wifi direct connection.
Basically create a listening application on the tablet that will wait for an action and do something then. Create another application on your phone that will send a command and why not, wait for an answer.

- Step 1:

  `[Phone] ----- (Command) ------> [Tablet]`
- Step 2:

  `[Tablet] === (ACTION) ===> [Tablet]` (The action returns a string with the response)
- Step 3:

  `[Tablet] ------ (Response) ------> [Phone]`

I invite you to read this page in the Android API to understand how to deal with Bluetooth: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

I also suggest you to take a look at this document about the way to establish a P2P Wifi connection between two devices: http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html